# How to Upload images to mysql database Using PHP/Flex

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, actionscript

I have been searching the net for some weeks now and can't find a solution to my issue.

I'm working on a Web application using `Flex(front-end)` and `PHP/MySql(Back-end)`.

Now I want to enable users to upload images for their profile Pictures... I was Uploading them to a Directory on the server. Now my Boss "feels" that they should be stored directly to the Database not only store the link of the Image but the whole content.

Please Help guys....I'm stuck!!!

Comment: Consider **not** doing that. There are lot's of flaws in storing regularly used images in DB. In example - `caching`. Browsers won't cache images that are called like `image.php?id=5423`. And then there is of course the DB size issue. If the images are large, you will create a large database, that will also work slower, then just calling the images from filesystem directly.

Comment: Yes Dainis I did consider that...I was using file Systems before, Now My Boss wants it to be Stored on the Database.

Comment: The only reason you should be thinking about this, if you want to protect your images from stealing. But even then, there are better solutions. I suggest, you gather all the facts about storing images in DB and prove to your boss, that such a move is a bad mistake and wrong in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in the form which you're uploading the file from, you should use the following the  tag:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

also you need to specify that field as one of the following:

> TINYBLOB
>   , BLOB
>   , MEDIUMBLOB
>   , LONGBLOB

Finaly modify this code for your db and that will do :)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
   $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
   $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
   $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
   $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

   $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
   $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
   $content = addslashes($content);
   fclose($fp);

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
}

$query = "INSERT INTO upload (name, size, type, content ) ".
"VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";

mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 

}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's best to store images on the filesystem (for speed and size).  For this, you could store the images in a location such as "images/profiles/{userID}.jpg".  If you did want to store the image in the database, just set the column type to `blob` and insert the image contents in there. A good article that details storing images in a mysql database is described [here](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql).